# Flattening lists containing 2-tuples and 1-tuples by splitting the 2-tuples

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with making lists like

```
[['G', 'U'], ['G', 'U'], 'R', 'G']
```

into all the possible combinations like the following

```
[['G', 'G', 'R', 'G'],
['G', 'U', 'R', 'G'],
['U', 'G', 'R', 'G'],
['U', 'U', 'R', 'G']]
```

in Python. How do I go about it?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, your data list is inconsistent--a mixture of a) lists of strings and b) strings. Is this the actual data, or are we to treat a string as a list containing one string?

Comment: It was the actual data and I had tried the itertools below but without the "*" argument infront of the list name, thus not giving me what I expected. I'm new around here so thanks for the guidelines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product()`:

```
lst = [['G', 'U'], ['G', 'U'], 'R', 'G']
from itertools import product
[x for x in product(*lst)]

#[('G', 'G', 'R', 'G'),
# ('G', 'U', 'R', 'G'),
# ('U', 'G', 'R', 'G'),
# ('U', 'U', 'R', 'G')]
```

Comment: Thank you, I did try itertools but it didn't give me what I wanted but rather this output:

#[(['G', 'U'],), (['G', 'U'],), (['R'],), (['G'],)]

Turns out I didn't use the *, beginner in Python. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). It does exactly what you describe.

```
>> import itertools
>> l = [['G', 'U'], ['G', 'U'], 'R', 'G']
>> i = itertools.product(*l)
>> list(i)
[('G', 'G', 'R', 'G'), ('G', 'U', 'R', 'G'), ('U', 'G', 'R', 'G'), ('U', 'U', 'R', 'G')]
```

Comment: Thank you, I did try itertools but it didn't give me what I wanted but rather this output:

#[(['G', 'U'],), (['G', 'U'],), (['R'],), (['G'],)]

Turns out I didn't use the *, beginner in Python. Thanks for all the help!